# Project build failed while testing project with maven and jvmdump file is created which shows nullpointerexception which is in Freemarker

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at freemarker.template.TemplateException.getFTLInstructionStack(TemplateException.java:233)
    at freemarker.template.TemplateException.printStackTrace(TemplateException.java:363)
    at freemarker.template.TemplateException.printStackTrace(TemplateException.java:339)
    at freemarker.template.TemplateException.printStackTrace(TemplateException.java:327)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.buildStackTrace(Utils.java:535)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.longStackTrace(Utils.java:519)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateTable(TestHTMLReporter.java:155)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateLog(TestHTMLReporter.java:311)
    at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.onFinish(TestHTMLReporter.java:40)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:772)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:741)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:509)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
```

This error comes while i run test by maven, but when i run test individually, its fine. Error is dumped in target/surefire-reports and the dump file is 2019-07-18T15-47-53_893-jvmRun1.dump. This error comes up when i try to catch exception in unit test that is passed. I have Freemerker Dependency in my project and this exception is of freemarker. here is the unit test.

```
    @Test(expectedExceptions = TemplateException.class)
    public void getTemplate_Unsuccessfull_TemplateException() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        //GIVEN
        //WHEN
        Mockito.when(configuration.getTemplate("someFile.ftl")).thenReturn(template);
        Mockito.doThrow(TemplateException.class).when(template).process(Mockito.any(Map.class),Mockito.any(Writer.class));

        //THEN
        TemplateService.getTemplate("abcd@gmail.com","123456");
    }
```

And this is console output

```
Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.743 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-18T16:42:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/382M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project ***: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to F:\*****\Project\****\branches\Authentication_20190508\Service\***\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] null
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] null
```

I expect to successfully run all tests by maven.

Comment: Weird... It's as if the exception object wasn't fully initialized and so the `lock` field of it is `null`. Just to be sure I'm looking at the correct line, which version of FreeMarker is this?

Comment: freemarker version is 2.1.6.RELEASE.

Comment: That's not a FreeMarker version. Anyway, my guess is that Mockito doesn't instantiate the `TemplateException` class properly. It must do some hack, as that class has no parameterless constructor, and I guess that goes wrong. So, I guess you can provide an instance to it that you create properly, instead of just the class, and then this will go away.